# How to invoke /usr/local/bin/g++-X instead of XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++

Tags: xcode, homebrew, gcc

{MacOS 10.14.1 Mojave, Xcode 10.1}

I'm working on building  the POPF planner under MacOS and I'm stuck on a system library include problem that I'm not sure how to overcome.

I have exported `export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8` and `export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++8` in my terminal, yet when I invoke `make VERBOSE=1`, the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++` compiler is still used rather than `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8`.
I have symlinked `/usr/local/opt/gcc@8/???-8 /usr/local/bin/???` (where the question marks represent `gcc, g++, c++, and cpp`).  I have also set aliases `alias gcc='gcc-8'`, `alias cc='gcc-8'`, `alias g++='g++-8'`, and `alias c++='c++-8'`.

This is causing the wrong system includes to be used:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/
```

instead of

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/
```

The Makefile does not override the setting, and when I execute `gcc --version` from the commandline, it returns `gcc-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.3.0) 8.3.0` and `c++ --version` returns `c++-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.3.0) 8.3.0`

Here is the build log:

```
user@host:[ 0:18]$ make VERBOSE=1
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -H/Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf -B/Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/CMakeFiles /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/depend
cd /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build && /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles/parsing /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles/parsing /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/build
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `src/VALfiles/parsing/CMakeFiles/ParsePDDL.dir/build'.
[ 10%] Built target ParsePDDL
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/depend
cd /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build && /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/build
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/parser.dir/build'.
[ 14%] Built target parser
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/depend
cd /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build && /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/build.make src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/build
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/instantiation.o
cd /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles -I/Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/build/src/VALfiles -I/Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles/parsing   -o CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/instantiation.o -c /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles/instantiation.cpp
In file included from /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles/instantiation.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/user/Programming/Planning/POPF/popf/src/VALfiles/parsing/ptree.h:55:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/map:479:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const Inst::ConstSymbolLT'
        {return static_cast<const _Compare&>(*this)(__x, __y.__cc.first);}
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What have I missed?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: CC=absolute path CXX=absolute path

Comment: Tried that, but still get the same problem.  :(

Comment: Ok, I worked it out.  I didn't realise that I needed to run `cmake ..` again.  I figured I would be able to simply change the compiler during the make phase.